# Generating Entire JPA Layer (Including finders with Dynamic Queries)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Can someone suggest a JPA Layer generator similar to NetBeans but which generates a complete layer by which i can search for any field or any combination of any fields on a particular table from the get-go.

I've tried Eclipse / NetBeans / Oracle Enterprise Pack - maybe i'm using the wrong options?

I used to use FireStorm DAO for the old DAO patterns - which was awesome and i was ready to go from day 1.

I would really like something that creates the whole thing.

i.e findByDynamicSelect(String sql, Object[] sqlParams)

Or am i missing the point completely? I get the feeling i am...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities come to my head:

- [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) generates entities and DAOs using commands. It does not generate every finder by every field, though and it mixes entities with DAOs which might not be acceptable to everyone and it leaves a dependency on AspectJ (which can be removed with extra work).
- [Spring-Data-JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) (formerly Hades) is not really a generator but it was my choice for a current project. After generating entities with Netbeans, we [use this API](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/) to avoid rewriting common code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll take a look at both. Appreciate the response!